# Error in C# code when converting from VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I converted the follwoing code from VB.Net:

```
Private Sub UVTapHuanLuyen_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    txtPath.Text = strPath & "Dulieu\"
    Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(txtPath.Text)
    Dim tenfile, FS() As FileInfo
    FS = di.GetFiles("*.txt")
    For Each tenfile In FS
        lstPath.Items.Add(tenfile.FullName)
    Next
    lblSoLuong.Text = lstPath.Items.Count
    rd_ThuSpam.Checked = True
End Sub
```

In the resulting c# code, I am getting an error with `txtPath.Text = strPath & "Dulieu\"`
I declared strPath Object in advance, but I still received an error again.
Here is code in C#:

```
 private void UV_Trains_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_Path.Text = strPath + "Dulieu\\";
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(txt_Path.Text);
        FileInfo tenfile = default(FileInfo);
        FileInfo[] FS = null;
        FS = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
        foreach (FileInfo element in FS) 
        {
            tenfile = element;
            lst_Path.Items.Add(txt_Path.Text);
        }
        lbl_Soluong.Text = lst_Path.Items.Count.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: It's a good idea to post the C# code that is causing the error. Right now, we can only guess why your code isn't working.

Comment: Show your declaration of strPath and where you declare it. My guess it is not a class scoped variable.

Comment: Please remember to mark responses as the correct answer if they solve your problem on this and other posts--it's good for your rep as well as for those who are helping you.

Answer (score 3):

In C#, the slash in `"Dulieu\"` indicates that the last quotation mark is part of the string. To fix it, you can use double slashes.

```
txtPath.Text = strPath + "Dulieu\\"
```

Alternatively, you can prefix the string literal with the `@` symbol to mark it as a verbatim string.

```
txtPath.Text = strPath + @"Dulieu\"
```

Comment: txtPath.Text = strPath + "Dulieu\\". The error is at strPath. It shows that the name "strPath" does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Well then your original post is misinformed. You say that you declared `strPath`, but the error says you didn't. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `&` with `+`.
In vb.net, `&` is a string concatenation operator, in c# the correct operator is `+`.

Comment: While true, how do you know this is an issue?  The OP has not shown his c# code, just the VB.

Comment: you're correct, he did not show his c# code, but he did paste in the code line that generated the exception (**txtPath.Text = strPath & "Dulieu\"**). However, Steven did notice something I've missed - the \" that should also be changed.